# Ubuntu Server 10.04 behind proxy. Ping works apt-get fails

Tags: 12.04, apt, proxy

I have installed 4 `ubuntu servers` on a virtual machine. same installation procedure where i set the proxy, domain, ip during the installation. it appears that 2 of the machine have no issues at all. both ping and apt-get. but for some unknown reason the other 2 can ping anything including `security.ubuntu.com` and `us.archive.ubuntu.com` but can't do `sudo apt-get update` .

so all of them have the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "10.10.19.21";
```

What i've noticed here is that there is no port number for any of them.Even with that 2 servers still can update via `apt-get`

for now there is no http_proxy set in either `/etc/environment`.

Can anyone help you? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting *Acquire::http::Proxy "10.10.19.21";* and set *http_proxy* in bashrc

Comment: Hello Thanks for the response. you mean at the end of `.bashrc` ? But to do any `apt-get` one needs to be sudo so won't it be best if it's something like `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment` ?

Comment: AFAIK when you use sudo to gain root access, this is actually your user which gives a temporary privilege to use system commands and all of your environmental variable are valid there